# Can't find Spray metadata page

Tags: scala, akka, spray

For development on C#, I use ServiceStack, it has metadata page for all api methods, looking like this: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Metadata-page
Does Spray has any analog?

Comment: It might make sense to take a look at spray-swagger: https://github.com/gettyimages/spray-swagger.